# jquery - thumbnails fading altogether instead of only the one I have my mouse over

Tags: jquery

I have a few thumbnails set up to fade on hover and reveal the post metadata. The problem is when I hover over one thumbnail, all of them fade.

You can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/LDs6C/10/

How can I make it so only the thumbnail I'm hovering over fades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still matching all the images and descriptions in your `hover` handler. You should restrict the selectors to the current thumbnail, e.g. by using `this` as the selector context:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(400, 0.2);
    $('.description', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    $('.description', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDs6C/11/).